# MongoDB query over several collections with one sort stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some data with identical layout divided over several collections, say we have collections named Jobs.Current, Jobs.Finished, Jobs.ByJames.

I have implemented a complex query using some aggregation stages on one of these collections, where the last stage is the sorting. It's something like this (but in real it's implemented in C# and additionally doing a projection):

```
db.ArchivedJobs.aggregate([ { $match: { Name: { $gte: "A" } } }, { $addFields: { "UpdatedTime": { $max: "$Transitions.TimeStamp" } } }, { $sort: { "__tmp": 1 } } ])
```

My new requirement is to include all these collections into my query. I could do it by simply running the same query on all collections in sequence - but then I still need to sort the results together. As this sort isn't so trivial (using an additional field being created by a $max on a sub-array) and I'm using skip and limit options I hope it's possible to do it in a way like:

- Doing the query I already implemented on all relevant collections by defining appropriate aggregation steps
- Sorting the whole result afterwards inside the same aggregation request

I found something with a $lookup stage, but couldn't apply it to my request as it needs to do some field-oriented matching (?). I need to access the complete objects.

The data is something like

```
{
  "_id":"4242",
  "name":"Stream recording Test - BBC 60 secs switch",
  "transitions":[
  {
    "_id":"123",
    "timeStamp":"2020-02-13T14:59:40.449Z",
    "currentProcState":"Waiting"        
  },
  {
    "_id":"124",
    "timeStamp":"2020-02-13T14:59:40.55Z",
    "currentProcState":"Running"        
  },
  {
    "_id":"125",
    "timeStamp":"2020-02-13T15:00:23.216Z",
    "currentProcState":"Error"        
  } ],
  "currentState":"Error"
}
```

Comment: can you post a s ample data?

Comment: @varman Is this sample helpful?

Comment: $sort operates on the current result set. It does not retrieve data from collections.

Comment: @D.SM But the result set retrieves data from a collection and I would like to retrieve data from several collections into one result set before sorting. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use $lookup for that.

Comment: @D.SM $lookup was the approach I tended to, too - but it's hard to understand how to use it only for collecting complete documents. To me it looks like being designed to collect single field's data.

Comment: What is "collecting"? Did you read documentation?

Comment: By "collecting" I mean to put all matching documents of sevberal collections into the result set. The docu says "localField: <field from the input documents>, foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>, as: <output array field>", but I don't want to go on specific fields and yet did not find out how to apply this concept on my requirement.